# How to merge two corresponding values of two different variables in arraylist?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, collections

```
I want to merge two corresponding values of two different variables with comma separator in a row :
```

like
Plate Numbers(Output) : MH 35353, AP 35989, NA 24455, DL 95405.

```
There is two different variables one is plate State and another is plate Number, I want to merge them together with their corresponding values like 1st values of plate State with 1st value of plate Number after that comma then so on..
```

I tried this code snippet but didn't work :

```
ArrayList<String> 
        list1 = new ArrayList<String>(); 

        list1.add("MH"); 
        list1.add("AP");
        list1.add("NA ");  
        list1.add("DL"); 

ArrayList<String> 
        list2 = new ArrayList<String>(); 

        list2.add("35353"); 
        list2.add("35989");
        list2.add("24455");
        list2.add("95405");

list1.addAll(list2);
```

Comment: ``ArrayList<String> list3 = new ArrayList<>(); list3.add(list1.get(0) + " " + list2.get(0));``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this :

```
 ArrayList<String> 
            list1 = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    
            list1.add("MH"); 
            list1.add("AP");
            list1.add("NA ");  
            list1.add("DL"); 
    
    ArrayList<String> 
            list2 = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    
            list2.add("35353"); 
            list2.add("35989");
            list2.add("24455");
            list2.add("95405");
    
     Iterator iterable = list2.iterator();
            List<String> list3 =list1.stream()
                 .map(x->{
                    x= x+" "+((String) iterable.next());
                    return x;})
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());

     String output = String.join(", ", list3);
                   System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: thanks, Code is fine but I want to store it in a string not in a list3(as you mentioned in the above code).

Comment: you want to store in ArrayList<String> list3   not in List<String> list3?

Comment: final result like String output = "MH 35353, AP 35989, NA 24455, DL 95405" ?

Comment: add this :   String output = String.join(" ", list3);

Comment: Output after adding this, MH  35353  AP  35989  NA   24455  DL  95405. No comma it's printing after every number plate. But the Expected output : MH 35353, AP 35989, NA 24455, DL 95405 is this.

Comment: String output = String.join(",  ", list3);  hope this will fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

From [ArrayList#addAll Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-):

> Appends all of the elements in the specified collection to the end of this list[...]

This is not what you want, because you actually don't want to append the objects, you want to merge the String of the first list with the String from the second list. So in a sense, not merge the List but merge the objects (Strings) in the lists.

The easiest (most beginner friendly) solution would be to just create a simple helper method yourself, that does what you need.

Something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    list1.add("MH");
    list1.add("AP");
    list1.add("NA");
    list1.add("DL");

    ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    list2.add("35353");
    list2.add("35989");
    list2.add("24455");
    list2.add("95405");

    ArrayList<String> combined = combinePlateNumbers(list1, list2);
    System.out.println(combined);
}

private static ArrayList<String> combinePlateNumbers(List<String> list1, List<String> list2) {
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

    if (list1.size() != list2.size()) {
        // lists don't have equal size, not compatible
        // your decision on how to handle this
        return result;
    }
    // iterate the list and combine the strings (added optional whitespace here)
    for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
        result.add(list1.get(i).concat(" ").concat(list2.get(i)));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Output:

```
[MH 35353, AP 35989, NA 24455, DL 95405]
```

Comment: I want to store final output in a simple string not in a list.